# Can not pass data as list from spring controller to view?

Tags: java, html, spring, list, thymeleaf

I use the following controller method to retrieve data from database

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/channel-detail"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String channelDetail(ModelMap model) {
    List<Channel> channels = channelService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("channelList", channels);
    return "channel-detail";
}
```

In my html page I am passing this channel list using Thymeleaf as follows

```html
<li class="channel-box" th:each="channels, rowStat : ${channelList}">
    <a th:href="@{/channels/channel-detail?channelId=__${channels.id}__}"  >
        <img th:src="@{/assets/dist/img/axn.png}" alt="AXN" />
        <span class="chn-name">AXN</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

What I expect is to iterate through the loop and show the content several times. My database contains 3 sets of entries of channels. So the content should be displayed 3 times. But it shows nothing when I load the html. What is the issue here?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you already make sure that your list is not empty?

Comment: Well, simple action is `channels.isEmpty()`. You could start with debugging or simple `System.out.println(channels.isEmpty());` then you will know if your list empty or not

Comment: already done it. thnks. list is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are using parenthesis for single uri

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/channel-detail"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Try using

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/channel-detail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Print the list in the controller and tell me if you see the items in the console.

Comment: List is not empty. I can see the elements in the console

Comment: Using {} does not matter which I use in other controllers as well and working fine.

Comment: Okay. Right click ->Inspect -> console 
Does this show any error in console?